# Is the source code of any Ethereum smart necessarily contract open?

Tags: contract-design, etherscan, assembly, opcode

I thought that any smart contract had open code. However, from time to time I'll encounter  smart contracts that have no publicly available **Solidiy** code,  on etherscan.

How can this be? Doesn't that go against the fundamental idea of the Ethereum as blockchain that everything is open and can be seen by anyone, publicly?

For instance

[image: no source code???]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you deploy a smart contract written in Solidity, the Solidity code isn't deployed to the blockchain. The solidity code is first compiled to bytecode by a compiler, and then the bytecode is deployed to the blockchain.

When you see Solidity code on for example Etherscan, this means the contract is [verified](https://etherscan.io/verifyContract).

What you see in the screenshot is the bytecode of a smart contract. With a good decompiler you will be able to decompile the bytecode to Solidity code. This way every contract, verified or not, is fully 'open source' on the Ethereum blockchain.
Etherscan has a decompiler build in which you can check out: [decompiler](https://etherscan.io/bytecode-decompiler)

Comment: why has smart contract not been decompiled automatically by etherscan?

Comment: For me the question sounds not like "How does it work" but rather "Why does it go against blockchain principles"